# How to set fortran flags with cmake

Tags: cmake, fortran

I'm trying to build a library (https://github.com/NOAA-EMC/NCEPLIBS) using cmake. I was able to do so earlier but the new compiler requires to set the "-Mfree" flag (or 'make' will generate some compilation errors). I have tried to do so by using the -DCMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS, but cmake seems to be simply ignoring it. Comparing the generated Makefiles (with and without -DCMAKE_Fortran_FLAGS) shows no difference between them. Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what compiler are you using on what platform? I didn't find any reference to a `-Mfree` compile option (only for Oracle compiler). Can you add the compilation error you are getting to the question?

Comment: The compiler is NVHPC (old PGI). The error message is 'NVFORTRAN-S-0021-Label field of continuation line is not blank'.

Comment: Did cou cleared the CMake cache (i.e., deleted the CMakeCache.txt file in the build directory) after adding the flag?

Comment: I cleaned and erased everything before trying with the flag to have a clean sheet.

Comment: Perfect. What happens if you provide your additional flag(s) in the `FFLAGS` environment variable before calling CMake, i.e. `FFLAGS=-Mfree`?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. It's the same result, I'm still getting the same error.